# Using std::chrono to make custom "SI unit" types

Tags: c++, c++11

`std::chrono::duration` is a great example of how to create "units" using `std::ratio`. `std::ratio` by itself is not very useful for a "units" library, and the two choices are either something like `Boost.Unit` (which can be very complicated to use) or to write it yourself (why reinvent the wheel?) Therefore I'm trying to write a wrapper around `std::chrono::duration` for some very basic types, like meter, feet, inches and centimeters.

Right now I feel like the way I've constructed the types is sloppy. It took me a while to get it right (at least for the test cases.)

I also haven't figured out a good way to "rename" the types either. I've considered creating a templated struct that inherits from duration and then just renames the typedefs.

Another concern I have is whether I should use `double` instead of `float` and if there's a better way to avoid floating point errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ratio>
#include <cmath>  /* for std::abs(double) */

// https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/newbie#floating-point-arith
// "Why doesn’t my floating-point comparison work?"
constexpr inline bool isEqual(double x, double y)
{
  const double epsilon = 1e-5;
  return std::abs(x - y) <= epsilon * std::abs(x);
  // see Knuth section 4.2.2 pages 217-218
}

int main()
{
    using meters = std::chrono::seconds;

    // There are 100 centimeters per meter
    using centimeters = std::chrono::duration<float, std::ratio_divide<meters::period, std::ratio<100>>>;

    // There are 2.54 centimeters per inch
    // and 39.3701 inches per meter
    using inches = std::chrono::duration<float, std::ratio_divide<centimeters::period, std::ratio<100, 254>>>;

    // There are 12 inches per foot
    using feet = std::chrono::duration<float, std::ratio_multiply<std::ratio<12>, inches::period>>;

    static_assert(inches(1) * 12 == feet(1), "");
    static_assert(centimeters(2.54) == inches(1), "");

    /* Thanks to rounding, inches(1) / 2.54 is 0.393701.
     * To get 0.3937007874, we need to use inches(1 / 2.54)
     * instead.
     */
    static_assert(inches(1 / 2.54) == centimeters(1), "");
    static_assert(centimeters(100) == meters(1), "");

    static_assert(inches(centimeters(100)) == meters(1), "");
    static_assert(isEqual(inches(centimeters(100)).count(), 39.3701), "");
}
```

Comment: We don't help you write new code, but we will be glad to address your other concerns.

Comment: @Hosch250 It was something as simple as `template <typename Rep, typename Period = std::ratio<1>> struct unit : public std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period> { using ratio = Period; };` I figured it was too "hypothetical" to include in the question.

Comment: As long as it works, it is welcome.

Comment: For a library going down this route, have a look at: https://github.com/mpusz/units

Answer (score 5):

**Meters are Not Seconds**

```
using meters = std::chrono::seconds;
```

I know it's obvious, but it bears stating. A `meter` is not a `second`. You compare a meter and a second, you cannot add them, etc. They are different types completely. So what you want is to make a different type:

```
template <typename T, class Ratio = std::ratio<1>>
class distance;

using meters = distance<int64_t>;
```

I'll leave the implementation of `distance` up to you. But it should absolutely be a different class than `seconds`!

**Use the Standard Ratios**

[`<ratio>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio) actually provides a bunch of standard ratios for your use. You should use them:

```
using centimeters = distance<int64_t, std::centi>;
```

You'll note that `std::centi` is `std::ratio<1, 100>`, which makes more sense for centimeters than `std::ratio<100>`.

**Use integral types**

You'll notice I used `int64_t` instead of `float` *or* `double`. Prefer using integers whenever possible to simply sidestep the issue of floating point arithmetic altogether.